# The identity map in two metric spaces is a homeomorphism

Tags: metric-spaces

We have given two metric spaces (M,$\tau_{d}$) and (M,$\tau_h$) whereby the metric $h$ is given as:

$h(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$.

Now I have to show that the function

$id_{M}$ : $(M, \tau_{d}) \rightarrow  (M,\tau_h)$ which sends $x \rightarrow x$ is a homeomorphism.

I don't know if it would suffice to say that the identity function is a homeomorphism following the fact that it is a bijection and continuous and would we therefore be done or if there might be a more specific, elegant way.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I realised that my problem is the fact that I would only know how to show that the identity is contnuous in the case that we have the same metric spaces. But how can you show it if we have two metric spaces with two different induced topologies?

Comment: Just show that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ if and only if $h(x_n,x) \to 0$.

Comment: Are you assuming that every continuous bijection is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that and the inverse function also has to be continuous, so 3 conditions

Comment: So, yes, the way to go is to prove that $\operatorname{id}_M$ is continuous in both directions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but how do we do it in the case that the metrics are not the same

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity of a function $f : X \to Y$ between two metric spaces $(X,\tau_g)$ and $(Y,\tau_h)$, where the metrics $g : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ and $h : Y \times Y \to [0,\infty)$ are given? If you do, apply that to the situation where $X=Y$ and $f = \text{Id}$.

Comment: $ x/(1+x)$ is a monotone continuous function on the positive reals

Answer (score 2):

Those two metrics induce the same topology. In other words, those are equivalent metrics. You will find a proof of that assertion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2022083/446262). So, since the continuity of a map depends only upon the topologies that you are working with, $\operatorname{id}_M$ is continuous in both directions.

Comment: i thank you for your answer, however i am still not fully clear how from the definition of the continuity in topological spaces we concluded that idM is continuous in both directions..

Comment: This is done in two steps. First: those two distances induce the same topology. Second: on *any* topological space $(M,\tau)$, $\operatorname{id}_M$ is a homeomorphism from $(M,\tau)$ onto itself. Is it clear now?