# Exercise 11, Section 20 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Show that if $d$ is a metric for $X$ , then
> $d′(x,y)=d(x,y)/(1+d(x,y))$
> is a bounded metric that gives the topology of $X$.

I rephrase this exercise to my taste:

> Show $\mathcal{T}_d =\mathcal{T}_{d’}$

**My attempt:** It is easy to check $d’(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$ inequality. $d’(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$ and lemma 20.2, shows that $\mathcal{T}_{d’}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_d$. Now how to show $\mathcal{T}_{d’}\supseteq \mathcal{T}_d$? Can we prove similar inequality $d(x,y)\leq C d’(x,y)$, where $C$ is some constant?

Comment: In that proof/post, before using $d(x,y)\leq 2d’(x,y)$ how to show $d(x,y)\leq 1$? Because $x=d(x,y)$. More explicitly let $\epsilon \gt 0$, take $\delta =\delta^{\prime}/2,$ where $\delta^{\prime}=\min \{ 1,\epsilon /2 \}$ so that $B_{d’}(x,\delta)\subseteq B_d (x,\epsilon)$. Proof: $y\in B_{d’}(x,\delta)$. Then $d’(x,y)\lt \delta$………

Comment: If the radius of the ball is $\epsilon>1$, you may "shrink" the ball to a radius of $1$ before proceeding further. The inclusions will still hold. I.e. $B_{d’}(x,\delta)\subseteq B_d (x,\min\{\epsilon,1\}) \subseteq B_d (x,\epsilon)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: You cannot prove similar inequality, it is clear if $d$ is unbounded.

Comment: @ArcticChar make sense.

Comment: @Momo kind of. Not completely. As I said in edit, there’s not a unique way to solve this problem. In this post we can discuss about different(from your approach) way to solve this problem. If you see my past posts, you’ll find out how much I like alternative solutions to the same problem.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far to call Lemma 20.2 "a different approach", it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Momo that’s means you don’t that proof, do you?

Comment: @Momo in that proof we don’t need any inequality. Relation between $d$ and $d’$ metric. For each $\epsilon$, take $\delta$……… taking $\delta$ is clever and we don’t use any relation between $d$ and $d’$ metric.

Comment: To apply the lemma to your problem you still need to find $\delta$ so that $B_{d’}(x,\delta)\subseteq B_d (x,\epsilon)$, so you still need some sort of inequality like the one I used.

Comment: @Momo understood. I understand what you mean to say, and that is somewhat true. In proof of $\mathcal{T}_{d’}\supseteq \mathcal{T}_d$. For each $\epsilon$, take $\delta =\frac {\epsilon}{\epsilon +1}$, claim:$ B_{d’}(x,\delta )\subseteq B_d (x,\epsilon)$. From this fact, form inequality. At least I wasn’t able to form any inequality.

Comment: @Momo Can you also please reply to my last comment in the post, you referred as duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2022105/861687